# Have data in mySQL database be reflective of what's displayed in a drop down menu.

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

Thanking you for taking the time to look at this question.

The premise of the situation is that I have a "website" written in PHP and HTML that displays items from my database named "Spreadsheet." There are six columns, and over 4000+ rows of data. The columns are "accountID", "accountName", "website", "rating", "imageURL", "comments." The column "rating" in the website is a drop down list.

Currently, everything works well, but I have do questions:

1. How do I, with PHP, have data submitted to the database upon clicking on an option (such as "Very Bad") in the drop down list? At the moment, it requires the user to click a "submit" button, which refreshes the page entirely, losing their position. Is it possible to have it submit silently (without refreshing)
2. Second question has to do with the drop-down list again. How do you have the drop-down list display what's in the database? For example, if rating is "Very Bad" in the database, the drop-down list reflects that, and not what the first element is.

Below is my code.

```
    <a href =\"". $urlHTTP, $row['website']."\">". $row['website']."</a><br />
  <Form Name =\"rating\" Method =\"POST\" ACTION =\"\" />

  <input type = \"hidden\" name=accountID value=" . $row['accountID'] . ">
    <select name=\"rating\">
    <option value=\"\"></option>
    <option value=\"Very Bad\">Very Bad</option>
    <option value=\"Bad\">Bad</option>
    <option value=\"Average\">Average</option>
    <option value=\"Above Average\">Above Average</option>
  </select>

      <INPUT TYPE =\"Submit\" Name =\"formSubmit\" VALUE =\"Submit\">


if (isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
    $rating = $_POST['rating'];
    $accountID = $_POST['accountID'];


var_dump($rating);
var_dump($accountID);


if(!mysql_query("UPDATE Spreadsheet SET rating='$rating' WHERE accountID='$accountID'")) {echo 1;}

}    
mysql_close();
?>
```

Thanks so much! This question has been bothering me for a bit. I have tried many Google attempts, but I could not find an answer as specific as I am asking. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to #1:**

You can use Javascript/AJAX to accomplish submitting the form without actually pressing submit.  There are various javascript libraries that can help you accomplish this a lot easier than bare bones Javascript, namely jQuery ( http://jquery.com/ ).  It's not a very complicated task but you will need to learn some basic Javascript and how to use jQuery.  The essential flow of things would be *when the form changes, submit an AJAX request to submit the form*.  You will need a second script to take the incoming AJAX request and do the save.  Try search engines for some basic jQuery tutorials, and once you have a basic grip, something like "ajax submit on form change jquery" will get you started.

**Answer to #2:**

Something like this (please see my notes...)

```
echo '<select name="rating" id="rating">';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT `option_name` FROM `options`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) { 
    echo '<option value="' . $row['option_name'] . '">' . $row['option_name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

If you would like the select preselected, that's pretty easy too!  Taking from the last example:

```
$pre_selected = "Very Bad";
echo '<select name="rating" id="rating">';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT `option_name` FROM `options`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) { 
    echo '<option value="' . $row['option_name'] . '"';
    if($row['option_name'] == $pre_selected) { 
      echo ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo '>' . $row['option_name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

But this is the part I'd like to point a few things out:

- Don't use the old mySQL library like you are using and my examples are using.  Please, use PDO, or at least mySQLi.  The functions you are using are deprecated, and may not be available in PHP for much longer.
- Please, escape your data properly.  Search for "SQL Injection" and you will find a massive amount of information about how your code is *very* insecure (your UPDATE, specifically) because you did not escape the values.
- Just a heads up, when/if you use jQuery, you're going to need to use `id="foo"` in addition to `name="foo"`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the input. This community has awesome people. I will read this and try to apply these changes.

On the SQL injections - thank you for the reminder for using deprecated functions.

Comment: Hello nezZario. The loop makes things much simpler, thank you. Can you tell me the difference between the "options" and "option_name" variable?

Comment: There is no `$option`s variable.  ``option_name`` in the query is meant to be the column that holds your option's values.  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Oh! I see. That is what I meant. So if I have five options, then I will give it a name (option_name) and type in the five options. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question you can look at ajax onchange event. Basically when you change select value you fill call function that can call php file to insert data in db.

For the second question you check the DB for selected value and if it matches option value or text you set it to selected

```
<select name=\"rating\">
<option value=\"\"></option>
<option value=\"Very Bad\">Very Bad</option>
<option value=\"Bad\">Bad</option>
<option value=\"Average\">Average</option>
<option value=\"Above Average\" 
<?php if($someValueFromDb=='Above Average'){
   echo 'selected=selected';}?>
 >Above Average</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I will make the changes and get back to you.

Comment: Hi vodich. Can you explain to me a bit more depth into the "selected" function? I am aware it is widely used in drop-down menus. It compares two given values (for example, a saved option vs. one chosen in a form) and, if the values are the same, adds the selected attribute to the current option tag. But I tried copying your code (and changing #someValueFromDb to $rating) but I don't think I am doing the correct thing.

Comment: Your $rating should be value of select option, and then you can check if $rating==value of select. Offcourse you should do it in a loop as nezZario suggested. Make sure you trim() all values because one space can give you much headache. You can echo your variables to see what you are getting from DB and what you actually expect